# How to obtain the height of tree in cutree() knowing the number of clusters

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am using hierarchical clustering to classify my data.

I would like to define the optimal number of clusters. To do so, the idea is to visualize a graph that the x-axis is the number of clusters, and the y-axis is the height of the tree in the dendrogram.

And to do so, I need to know the height of the tree when the number of clusters K is specified, for example if K=4, I need to know the height of tree after the command

```
cutree(hclust(dist(data), method = "ward.D"), k = 4)
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heights are stored in the `hclust` object.  Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate with the built-in iris data.

```
HC = hclust(dist(iris[,1:4]), method="ward.D")
sort(HC$height)
<reduced output>
[133]   1.8215623   1.8787489   1.9240172   1.9508686   2.5143038   2.7244855
[139]   2.9123706   3.1111893   3.2054610   3.9028695   4.9516315   6.1980126
[145]   9.0114060  10.7530460  18.2425079  44.1751473 199.6204659
```

The biggest value is the height of the first split. Second biggest is second split, etc. 
You can see that this gives the heights that you need by plotting.

```
plot(HC)
abline(h=10.75,col="red")
```

[image: Dendrogram]

You can see that the fourth biggest height matches the height of the fourth split.